# Reaplce_na in all columns starting with "CPA" R

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

I have a table with columns like CPA_A to CPA_U.
I want to create a new column X as the sum of CPA_A to CPA_U in DPLYR.
I tried something like

```
 mutate(sum_onCPA = rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = grep("CPA", names(M_bridge)))
```

but it does not work.
Any clue?

Comment: I think you mixed `dplyr` with `data.table`

Comment: You can just do `data %>%
 mutate(sum_onCPA = rowSums(select(., starts_with("CPA"))))`.

Comment: Why do you have `replace_na` in your title ? What it has to do here ?